# How to add a some condition in jquery click event?

Tags: jquery

I have a many elements with "click" events.
How to add a some condition in jquery click event for all buttons ? Override standart click event ?

for example:

```
if ( my_condition ) {
    return click();
}    else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It largely depends on condition itself. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to target all buttons

1. use the button selector
2. override the click event
3. if your condition is true, perform some function and/or prevent the default click behavior.

```
$(':button').click(function(event){

    if (someCondition){
        doSomeFunction();
        event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

If the condition is false, then this shouldn't interrupt the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$("input[type='button']").bind("click", buttonClick);

buttonClick = function(e) {
    if (someCondition) {
       $(this).unbind("click"); // remove the click for element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind,

```
$('#MY-BTNS').bind('click', function() {

if(my_conditions)
  alert('User clicked on "foo."');
});
```

or you can extend `jQuery.click();`

But in my opinion, it is better to use bind.

Comment: jQuery's `click()` method is simply a shortcut for `.bind('click', handler)`. See the docs for more: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: thanks, I mean that instead of overwriting the click behaver it is better to change it on exact bind.